# Creating a Coutdown Timer from a value in a Databse

Tags: android, sqlite, handler, countdowntimer

I would like to pull a value from a database and use this in a countdown timer. It seems that its not possible to do with CountDownTimer but looks like it might be achievable with a Handler. Can anyone provide an example?

I'm using Android Studio

Thanks

here's my timer class:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.CountDownTimer;
    import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Mat on 14-Feb-17.
 */

    public class Timer extends Activity{

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        // 15000 is the starting number (in milliseconds)
        // 1000 is the number to count down each time (in milliseconds)


        MyCount counter = new MyCount(DisplayTime2(), 1000); // <--- 
        counter.start();
    }


    private long DisplayTime2(Cursor d) {  //  <------------
        return (d.getLong(2));
    }

    // count down timer is an abstract class, so extend it and fill in methods
    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // it's done
            textView.setText("Done!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textView.setText("Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
    }


    }
```

Here's my DatabaseAccess Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseAccess {
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static DatabaseAccess instance;
private static  String DATABASE_TABLE = "Cardio";
static final String KEY_ROWID = "rowid";
static final String KEY_NAME = "Exercise";

/**
 * Private constructor to aboid object creation from outside classes.
 *
 * @param context
 */
public DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}

/**
 * Return a singleton instance of DatabaseAccess.
 *
 * @param context the Context
 * @return the instance of DabaseAccess
 */
public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

/**
 * Open the database connection.
 */
public void open() {
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

/**
 * Close the database connection.
 */
public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        this.database.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Read all quotes from the database.
 *
 * @return a List of quotes
 */
public List<String> getQuotes() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM quotes", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
public Cursor getRProgram() {
    Cursor mCursor= database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME},null,null,null,null,"RANDOM()");
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

}
```

here's my MainActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Generate);
    generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DatabaseAccess myDatabaseHelper = new    DatabaseAccess(MainActivity.this);
            myDatabaseHelper.open();
            Cursor d = myDatabaseHelper.getRProgram();
            if (d.moveToFirst()) ;
            DisplayProgram(d);
            myDatabaseHelper.close();

        }

        public void DisplayProgram(Cursor d) {
            TextView result2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result2);
            result2.setText("\n" + d.getString(1));
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: you want a countdown timer ? or any additional thing ? did you pull the value by yourself first ?

Comment: see You have Called `DisplayTime2()` but it needs to be called with a Cursor! you call like this `MyCount counter = new MyCount(DisplayTime2(), 1000);` and your method `private long DisplayTime2(Cursor d)` is like this which is waiting for parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a countdown from 15 to 0. You can get the value what you want and pass it to the place where I used 15000(milliseconds)

```
 public class YourClass extends Activity {

        TextView textView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

            // 15000 is the starting number (in milliseconds)
            // 1000 is the number to count down each time (in milliseconds)
            MyCount counter = new MyCount(15000, 1000); // PASS YOUR VALUE INSTEAD  15000 Here
            counter.start();
        }


        // count down timer is an abstract class, so extend it and fill in methods
        public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

            public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // it's done
                textView.setText("Done!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                textView.setText("Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks charu, I'll give it a go and see how I get on :-)

Comment: @Matmajot  did you check that ;)

Comment: Hi Charu, I've tried but am having a problem putting the database Value in place of the 1500

Comment: here's the code   MyCount counter = new MyCount(DisplayTime(), 1000); // PASS YOUR VALUE INSTEAD  15000 Here
        counter.start();
    }
    
    private void DisplayTime(Cursor d) {
        int DBTime = Integer.parseInt((d.getString(2)));
        
    }

Comment: @Matmajot  ill check and let you know

Comment: have also tried this                                                                                                                                MyCount counter = new MyCount((DisplayTime()), 1000); // PASS YOUR VALUE INSTEAD  15000 Here
        counter.start();
    }

    private int DisplayTime(Cursor d) {
        return Integer.parseInt((d.getString(2)));

Comment: Wondered if it was something to do with the timer needing a "long" value so changed it to:                                                                                             MyCount counter = new MyCount(DisplayTime2(), 1000); // PASS YOUR VALUE INSTEAD  15000 Here
        counter.start();
    }


    private long DisplayTime2(Cursor d) {
        return (d.getLong(2));
    }

Comment: @Matmajot  with the new navigation bar update i am fully messed up :P reading what you posted

Comment: Okay what is your problem `MyCount counter = new MyCount(yourTimeValue, 1000);` this is the line you need to concern to work an it works in my example! If you have an issue thats because of **yourTimeValue**  whats the value that you passed there ?

Comment: Cursor d uses the Random function to pull a value from the database. The value is an int and is either 30, 45, 60, 120 or 180

Comment: @Matmajot then you cannot directly put that value if you meant 30 for 30 mins you should multiply by 1000 and set that,cuz its miliseconds!! have you done that? Is that the issue you had ?

Comment: no it doesnt seem to be. I have now changed this to  private long DisplayTime2(Cursor d) {
        return (d.getLong(2)*1000); but I'm still getting the same error. There is a red mark underneath the () at this part: new MyCount(DisplayTime2(). If I hover over it it says "DisplayTimer2 (Cursor) in Timer cannot be applied to               ()"  note the many spaces is not a typo, thats how its displayed

Comment: @Matmajot forget about the courser return value keep it as it was without any error hard code the value that i gave  in my example and tell me if it works if yes we ll go through your real issue which was not the issue in my method

Comment: its taken out the spaces so have used "S" to represent a space.  "DisplayTimer2 (Cursor) in Timer cannot be applied to S S S S S S S ()"

Comment: ah ok - will give it a go

Comment: @Matmajot  you can accept my answer and check the comment i gave you ,you are not calling the method in the right way. you need to fix that first you **method needs a parameter** but you call it without any! Check your Timer class

Comment: Sorry Charu, I'm at a loss on how to do that, can you be more specific, or provide an example. I'm a noob at this programming!

Comment: @Matmajot Its not the method that i created what i can tell you is this, check your method called **DisplayTime2** --> its like this **DisplayTime2(Cursor d)** it has a parameter which accepts a Cursor you named it as d, so you cannot call this method as `DisplayTime2()` ! You should call it as **DisplayTime2(yourCurserObjectThatYouNeedToPass)**

Comment: Second I dont see that your method DisplayTime2  points to anywhere.Does It? What you should do is find where you get that values like 30, 45, 60, 120 or 180 and you can pass that value to my method call after multiplying by 100 ?  Do you know where you get that 30, 45, 60, 120 or 180 if yes i can tell you how to pass them !

Comment: My DisplayTime2 method is below. I thought that this would return the value of what was in location 2 and then convert it to milliseconds by *1000?             private long DisplayTime3(Cursor d) {
        return (d.getLong(2)*1000);

Comment: I get the values 30,45 etc from the Database. I thought I was using Cursor d to access the database and return values from the 3rd column which is where those integers are stored

Comment: easy way will be this forget about the timer. you need to get a value to pass to that! So get that first. And thats up to you.Or it should be posted as a separate question? How to get the valve of something from database and use it in X Class. Once it is fixed you have a value. Dont go to cast value if you mess up. you can use `MyCount counter = new MyCount(yourCurserReturnValue*1000, 1000);`

Comment: You said  **I get the values 30,45** where ? in which line ?If you can get that and point the line then i can guide you how to use that ? If you dont get a one and just assuming you will have a value you should post that in another question how to get your value,what ever the question of your time problem has the answer here.Your issue is you are not able to get the value form db correctly

Comment: ok thank you Charu. I have now been able to compile the code without errors. When I try and run the code in the emulator it crashes with a Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference. I'll start a new question for that one. thanks very much for your help :-)

Comment: @Matmajot  well that has a 99% possibility to get closed by what is null pointer and how do i fix it :) you can accept my answer here if it helps will give you points as well , make sure you have assigned a value to that if there is no value assigned it will be null thats the point

Comment: Hi Charu, I'll accept the answer thank you. I'll also change it so it outputs to a textview to ensure its pulling a value from the database

Comment: @Matmajot yes you need to find how to get that value if you already got that value successfully then i can help further if you need ;)

Comment: ok, I've checked and I wasnt pulling the value from the database, however I've now rectified that but am still getting an error. I'll start another questions for it, but if you would help that would be great, thanks

Comment: here's alink to the new question:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252255/unable-to-use-database-value-in-countdowntimer